# How to show same selected value in two spinner in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am new in android programming. I have a layout with two spinner in my app. Both spinner have same values filled. If I change the values  of first spinner, the second spinner also replaced with same value as selected in the first spinner.

Anybody please replay with necessary solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same [adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) for both your spinners, or use two adapters filled with the same elements. In the latter case, you'll want to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` on both adapters when one is modified.

Answer (score 0):

**Activity Code:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Spinner spinner1,spinner2;

    private String[] numbers= {"One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six", "Seven", "Eight","Nine", "Ten"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numbers);

        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter_state);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter_state);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                spinner1.setSelection(position);
                spinner2.setSelection(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                spinner1.setSelection(position);
                spinner2.setSelection(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

try this.. hope it helps..